# How do I get the link and title from this (part of) html string in python

Tags: python, html-parsing, xbmc

I'm writing a plugin for xbmc in python. I have got a list of strings in the format:
`<a href="/www.link.to/something">name of link</a>`

By using beautiful stone soup (the relevant part of the code):

```
 soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(link, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.XML_ENTITIES)
    programs = soup('ul')
    i = 0
    for prog in programs:
        i = i+1
        if i==(5+getLetterValue(name)):
            j = 0
            while j < len(prog('li')):
                li = prog('li')[j]
                link = li('a')[0]
```

`getLeterValue` is a function that returns an index which indidcates where this specific 'ul' tag is placed (according to the desired letter).

Now I want to split link in the link and text. I tried using re.compile:
`match=re.compile('<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>').findall(link.string)`
but all I get is `match=[]`

What have I done wrong?

**Note:**
I know I should regexp html code but I'm not sure this ``rule'' is valid for small string. Also, for some reason this is almost a standard in xbmc plugin writing and I assume there is some reason for that.

Comment: If **link.string** is like **<a href="/www.link.to/something">name of link</a>** , the regex's pattern is correct to match them. But don't call an object with the identifier 'match', I don't think that you override the **re**'s method **match**, but that's dangerous

Comment: You should use ``for i,prog in enumerate(programs):``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not let BeautifulSoup give you the href [attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags) and the [element contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#contents)?

Comment: Great tool. However, I still need the string, ``name of link`` in my question.

Comment: That's also in the *same docs*.  Edited the answer with a paste from the *docs*.

Comment: I have found about contents about 15 minutes before you answered me, thanks. I still have a problem though. I think it has something to do with the Hebrew with the webpage. The answer I get is in the format of [u'\u50e0...'] and I can't figure how to convert that to a unicode string.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. I toyed around with it and I couldn't have convert this into Hebrew. I'll ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use lxml:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

elem = fromstring(link.string)
print elem.attrib["href"]
print elem.text
```

Comment: **lxml** is slower than BeautifulSoup , which is itself slower than pure regex. One time I measured **lxml** being 100 times slower than a code using uniquely regexes.